# Can I put a gazebo on top of an elevated paver patio?

Tags: pavers, gazebo

I have a pretty tall (almost 4 ft tall) patio deck where the top is pavers.  I'd like to get new outdoor furniture but I'd like to put it under a gazebo.  Is it odd to put a gazebo on top of a patio that is not only very high up but also is completely pavers. [The gazebo I am looking at](https://sunjoyshop.com/products/sunjoy-12-ft-x-12-ft-cedar-framed-octagon-gazebo-with-2-tier-steel-roof?variant=36021102968986&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=CjwKCAjw1YCkBhAOEiwA5aN4Aa_ryt5MXSZTrMLYWCVhlopUvp18aWELWwAJdMioF0iPgR60456QqBoCLzUQAvD_BwE)

Aside from looks or whether I can put it on top of a paver based patio, how do I secure it on to pavers?  I live in Michigan which isn't too windy but we do get some random weather throughout the year.

My patio is high because we used a lot of crushed concrete and a paver base directly under the pavers.  My kitchen sliding back door when you exit it was so far from the ground...when I got my patio built I did not want more then one step from the sliding door of my kitchen onto the top of the patio.  Because of this the landscape guys I had used a lot of crushed concrete (I mean at least 6-9 trucks of it) and load the crushed concrete as the base of this patio.  Then after the crushed concrete was wet and flattened (leveled) they used paver base (which is a gray fine grain with little bits of rocks) as the layer directy above the crushed concrete.   The pavers are then placed on top of this paver base and we followed it up with polymeric sand to fill in all the paver gaps.  All of that crushed concrete was used to get it real high up.

Comment: What is a "tall patio"?   Is it on columns?  On a mound?  On a roof?  Presuming the pavers are just resting unattached to whatever is beneath them, the answer to your question has nothing to do with the pavers.

Comment: Under it is a bunch of crushed concerete and paver base.  Yes retaining wall, no wood here all pavers on the top and retaining wall via paver blocks ( i dont know what they call these blocks) and under it a sh** load of crushed concrete.

Comment: @jay613 its high because my kitchen sliding door to the backyard is high up so my house is high up...because of this I wanted the patio not to have too many steps to go from this sliding door to the top of the patio.  Because of this we used a ton of crushed concrete.

Comment: @isherwood - no problem thank you for the direction.

Comment: Great so I think you should revise the question to say you want to attach the Gazebo to a patio that is sitting on a pile of crushed concrete between a house and a retaining wall.  The options would be to attach it to the house, the wall, or to put posts (wood, concrete, other)  into the ground below it.   Pictures and details will matter.

Comment: Gazebos shouldn't be attached to the house structure. That would require frost footings anyway.

Comment: @jay613 - I added the last paragraph.

Comment: @JonH so do you have a patio, or do you have a deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the instructions](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0462/6261/6218/files/A102007901_AI_EN_2022.03.26.pdf?v=1662363753):

> The gazebo is to be anchored onto the ground for added safety. Do not assemble the gazebo onto soil/earth ground. It is best advisable to have the gazebo built onto a wooden deck or concrete ground for stability. If it is to be build onto a wooden deck/ground, do ensure that the wooden deck/ground has a strong foundation. It is advisable to use appropriate floor plugs (not provided) to anchor the gazebo onto the wooden/concrete ground.

You can consider your pavers to be "soil" or "ground". They're flooring, not a foundation. They aren't that heavy and aren't anchored.

This (and common sense) means that you'll need to install wind-rated anchors, concrete footings, or some other means of preventing your shiny new roof from becoming a long-legged stealth bomber in a stiff breeze.

Word to the wise: Any product like this which has pictures for instructions is likely to disappoint in the way of quality. I'd bet that every component is *barely* up to the task, and that it's more subject to storm damage than something you'd source more locally (read: from this side of Earth). I would be looking for plans and a robust hardware kit where you provide the lumber, not a complete package in a box.